# How to log complete Request /Response of aws api gateway rest api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-api-gateway

As the title says: How can I log all the information of request and response of AWS Api Gateway Rest api including the body?
Few things that are on my mind:

1. **Cloudwatch**: Reject because there is a limit of 1024 bytes + we cannot log request/response body and headers.
2. **Create a lambda function** `Logger` which would log the details in a database and integrate it in between the endpoints like this:
   Client Request ===> `Logger` (for logging request) ===> processing   ===> `Logger` (for logging response) ===> send response to client. (How can I intergrate this `Logger` lambda function?)
   The Logger will act as middleware for all the api gateway calls

Comment: Using option 2 you can use the logger in a basic implementation of lambda which acts as a basic passthrough that will then call the end target. AWS Step functions might be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@srp321 's comment is the answer. Step function. Normal lambda function does not chain through api gateway.